# How to see our angular app through url after deploying it in azure cloud?

Tags: angular, azure, cloud, angular6

I have deployed my angular app in azure. It is up & running. But I don't know how to see it through browser. It is running in its default port 4200. Can someone please tell me if any configuration needs to be done to view the app in my browser.

Comment: Is this running in an Azure web app, on a VM, in a container?

Comment: @SamCogan It is running on a VM

Answer (score 0):

As this is running on a VM then you need to do the following:

- Open port 4200 in the Network Security Group (NSG) that is assigned that VM or Subnet the VM is in (or both)
- Open port 4200 in any firewall
- Ensure that the VM has a public IP address

Once you have done this you should be able to go to the public IP in the browser.

Comment: No, still I'm not able to view my app in the browser

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information than that if you want some help. What have you done, what error are you seeing, how have you configured things.

Comment: We have deployed our angular app in to azure VM. The application is up & running in cmd, But we couldn't knw how to view the app in the browser. Do we need to configure anything? Could you please tell me?

Comment: I said what needed to be done in the answer above. Have you ammended the NSG and firewall rules to allow access?